# How can I re-format (not validate) the value of a field that a user inputs into a node?

Tags: forms

I am using the Addressfield module to allow users to input addresses.  I am then using the Location Taxonomize module to generate a taxonomy based on these addresses.

To make everything consistent, I would like to automatically capitalize the first (and only the first) letter of every word (I know there are exceptions where multiple words should be capitalized, but I am willing to deal with those manually).

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 6, you could do something with the nodeapi() hook, eg,

```
function MYMODULE_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL)

  if ($node->type=='TYPEOFNODE' && $op == 'presave') {
    $node->field_WHICHEVERFIELD[0]['value']=ucwords($node->field_WHICHEVERFIELD[0]['value']);
  }

  // other nodeapi()ing goes here

}
```

In Drupal 7, you could use the node_presave() hook with similar logic.